# Given a function, f, How should f(1) be defined so that f is continuous at 1?

Tags: analysis, continuity

So the function is defined as:

$f(x) = \frac{x^2+3x-4}{x^2-1}$

And the question is: How should $f(1)$ be defined so that f is continuous at 1?

My thinking is that based on the definition of continuity, I have to control the function by delta = 1? Not quite sure how to though.

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$

Comment: Reduce $f(x) = \frac{x^2+3x-4}{x^2-1}$ to $f(x) = \frac{x+4}{x+1}$ for $x \ne 1$. Where does this converge as x goes to 1?

Comment: Maybe factorizing the numerator and the denominator should help.

Answer (score 0):

Clue: $x^2+3x-4 =(x+4)(x-1)$ and consider the limit of $f $ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $f$ to be continuous in $x = 1$, we want that:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = f(1)$$

So, we only need to solve $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$.

Now,

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x)$$

$$= \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2+3x-4}{x^2-1}$$

$$= \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x+4)}{(x-1)(x+1)}$$

$$= \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x+4}{x+1}$$

$$= \frac{5}{2}$$

So, we define $f(1) := \frac{5}{2}$ to make sure $f$ is continuous at $x = 1$

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of continuity, you need $$f(1) = \lim_{x\to1} f(x).$$

So calculate $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$ and you will have your answer.